# Regarding a JButton and an ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am currently reading a book on java, and I am currently studying the swing graphical user interface components. While I was doing so, I stumbled upon a code example, where the author was setting an image on a JButton with a very unusual way, depicted below:

```
Icon bug1 = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "bug1.gif" ) );
```

In order for the above to work, you need to have the image on the same folder as the .class files. Can someone explain to me why is he using this particular code (which as far as I know, it must be reflection code, but then again, I am not particularly sure about this one) and if there is one way for me to do the same thing, without getting things as complicated as he does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things are complicated only if you don't understand them. Once you have understood what the above code does, it will be extremely simple.

`getClass()` returns the Class object of the current object (`this`). `getResource()` called with a relative path as above, looks for a file, in the classpath, named bug1.gif, and in the same package as the Class object being called. So it looks for bug1.gif in the same package as the class containing the above code. `getResource()` returns a URL. And the `ImageIcon` constructor takes a URL as argument, loads the image bytes from this URL, and constructs an ImageIcon from these bytes.

So the whole thing just creates an ImageIcon from a file available from the classpath, in the same package as the class calling this code. And this makes sense: you put the images used by a given class in the same package as the class, and you release a jar containing the classes and the images of the application.

You would have figured all this by yourself by reading the javadoc of all these methods.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I had already understood what the above code did, well, in a sense at least, but I wanted someone better at this than I am to explain it to me, for me to see if I got it right from the beginning. Thank you for your clarifying answer, again.

Comment: I realize I haven't really answered your doubts and wondrings: there is no simpler or easier way to do that (but I don't see how it could be simpler), and it's not at all an unusual way: that's the typical way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Java's Swing can get over complicated really fast and I think he's actually using this code for simplicity.

If the image path is relative (the path in your example is), the image has to be located in the same location as the compiled byte code of your program, the .class files.  If the image was anywhere else, your program simply couldn't find it.

Relative paths like this are very useful especially when you want to compile your finished project into a JAR file.  Your image will be included in the JAR with all your .CLASS files.  You will be able to download your compile program, run it, and your images will be right there in your GUI as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

`Class#getResource(String)` returns an URL to resource from the classpath. This is a convinient way of loading resources that are stored inside your application JAR file. If the image lies somewhere on the HDD, you can load it using:

```
new ImageIcon(new File("/path/to/the/image").toURI().toURL());
```

which creates the `File` object, and gets it's path as URL (which will look like `file:///path/to/the/image`).

Or even easier, as `ImageIcon` has a contructor that takes a fileName:

```
new ImageIcon("/path/to/the/image");
```

Comment: *"an image on a JButton"* hints at being an embedded resource.  `File` objects are not suitable for accessing resources in a Jar.

Comment: That's why I specifically wrote _if the image lies somewhere on HDD_. Opening files (resources) from classpath in Java is overcomplicated, and can be hard to understand for a beginner (it took me some time), I just wanted to simplify the case, by showing how it works with external files which - in my opinion - is easier to understand.

Comment: I think using `toURI().toURL()` is the case when your filename contains characters that need to be escaped for URL. Which is rarely the case. Or could you explain?

Comment: I tested it, and `ImageIcon` loads the file properly with `file.toURL()`, even if filename contains spaces. 

You are right however, that it's not a good example to follow. And `File#toURL()` is deprecated too. 

I fixed the code.